# How to build OCaml reference manual for an opam switch?

Tags: ocaml, opam

I like to have a local copy of the ocaml reference manual that correspond to the current version I'm using, so I used to build the documentation when I was compiling ocaml from source.

Now that I use opam, I was wondering if it was possible to ask it to build the documentation when I create a new switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but you can install a matching version of the manual with

```
opam install ocaml-manual
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the reference manual and documentation for all installed packages via the [odig utility](https://erratique.ch/software/odig),

```
opam install ocaml-manual odig odoc #installs necessary packages
odig odoc # builds the documentation (takes a while)
odig doc  # opens the built documentation in your browser
```

You can also use `odig` to search for packages and otherwise explore your opam installation.